# Stripe: How to hold a place the payment for A range of price

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I wonder to find a solution for payment using Stripe. My clients create an event and we split the bill all members who joins the event. Let's say a football game $100 / 10 players, we hold a place until cancellation term is expired, or the game is canceled. What I am looking for solution and if it is possible to make, for the same event, instead of 10 players, 15 joined or 5 only, which means the bill from each varies from $6.60 to $20. I want these players to see that range of the pricing from $6.60 to $20 and book their spot and agree that when event occurs, they will be charged anything between. I remember that was the same solution with Uber at the beginning. Can anyone share any ideas if it is still possible to create this way, maybe they are new legislation and we need to show the total amount. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use Stripe to save payment info and then charge your customers later](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse):

> The [Setup Intents API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents) lets you save a customer’s card without an initial payment. This is helpful if you want to onboard customers now, set them up for payments, and charge them in the future—when they’re offline.

You may also be interested in [placing a hold on a card and capturing funds later](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later), assuming the time limits work for your use case.